# Combo box hiding the last letter from selected field option

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs6

I'm using `ExtJS 6.0.2` and having problem with combo box `growToLongestValue` property.

Please find sencha fiddle here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1e2k

Note - I have intentionally added same size of field options here.

Problem is `growToLongestValue` work exactly, but it hide the last letter when I select field options from combo box.

Comment: This is a bug you should report in Sencha Forum. They won't fix it for at least half a year, [like the similar issue with growAppend](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?306326-growAppend-causes-scroll-bar&p=1119291), but you should report it nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Alexander said, this appears to be a bug in the framework. Adding `growAppend: WW` should fix your problem

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel : 'Field',
        margin : 10,
        growAppend : 'WW',
        store : ['12345678', '12345678', '12345678', '12345678'],
        grow : true,
        growToLongestValue : true,
        renderTo : Ext.getBody()
    });

   }
});
```